# Complex XML data entry

Tags: xml, excel, xml-parsing, xsd

I have a complex XML Scheme, Excel wont accept such complex code but i have a database of 2500 entries which i need in the XML format, If there is anyway through which it could be done. I even dont mind using any software or something.

The XML Schema File looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
                 <xs:element name="ENVELOPE">
               <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                           <xs:element name="HEADER">
                                 <xs:complexType>
                                       <xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element name="TALLYREQUEST" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                       </xs:sequence>
                                 </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                           <xs:element name="BODY">
                                 <xs:complexType>
                                       <xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element name="IMPORTDATA">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:sequence>
                                                               <xs:element name="REQUESTDESC">
                                                                     <xs:complexType>
                                                                           <xs:sequence>
                                                                                 <xs:element name="REPORTNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                 <xs:element name="STATICVARIABLES">
                                                                                       <xs:complexType>
                                                                                             <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                   <xs:element name="SVCURRENTCOMPANY" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                             </xs:sequence>
                                                                                       </xs:complexType>
                                                                                 </xs:element>
                                                                           </xs:sequence>
                                                                     </xs:complexType>
                                                               </xs:element>
                                                               <xs:element name="REQUESTDATA">
                                                                     <xs:complexType>
                                                                           <xs:sequence>
                                                                                 <xs:element name="TALLYMESSAGE" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                                       <xs:complexType>
                                                                                             <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                   <xs:element name="VOUCHER">
                                                                                                         <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                               <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="BASICBUYERADDRESS.LIST">
                                                                                                                           <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                 <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="BASICBUYERADDRESS" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                 </xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                 <xs:attribute name="TYPE" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                     </xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="DATE" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="GUID" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="VOUCHERTYPENAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="VOUCHERNUMBER" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="REFERENCE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="PARTYLEDGERNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="PARTYNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="BASICBASEPARTYNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="CSTFORMISSUETYPE"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="CSTFORMRECVTYPE"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="FBTPAYMENTTYPE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="BASICBUYERNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="BASICDATETIMEOFINVOICE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="BASICDATETIMEOFREMOVAL" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="VCHGSTCLASS"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="DIFFACTUALQTY" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="AUDITED" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="FORJOBCOSTING" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="ISOPTIONAL" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="EFFECTIVEDATE" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="USEFORINTEREST" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="USEFORGAINLOSS" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="USEFORGODOWNTRANSFER" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="USEFORCOMPOUND" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="ALTERID" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="EXCISEOPENING" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="USEFORFINALPRODUCTION" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="ISCANCELLED" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="HASCASHFLOW" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="ISPOSTDATED" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="USETRACKINGNUMBER" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="ISINVOICE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="MFGJOURNAL" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="HASDISCOUNTS" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="ASPAYSLIP" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="ISCOSTCENTRE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="ISDELETED" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="ASORIGINAL" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="LEDGERENTRIES.LIST" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                                                                           <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                 <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="LEDGERNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="GSTCLASS"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="LEDGERFROMITEM" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="REMOVEZEROENTRIES" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="ISPARTYLEDGER" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="AMOUNT" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST">
                                                                                                                                             <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                                   <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="NAME" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="BILLTYPE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="AMOUNT" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                   </xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                             </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                       </xs:element>
                                                                                                                                 </xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                     </xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="ALLINVENTORYENTRIES.LIST">
                                                                                                                           <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                 <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="STOCKITEMNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="ISAUTONEGATE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="RATE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="AMOUNT" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="ACTUALQTY" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="BILLEDQTY" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="ACCOUNTINGALLOCATIONS.LIST">
                                                                                                                                             <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                                   <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="LEDGERNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="GSTCLASS"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="LEDGERFROMITEM" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="REMOVEZEROENTRIES" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="ISPARTYLEDGER" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="AMOUNT" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                   </xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                             </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                       </xs:element>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="BATCHALLOCATIONS.LIST">
                                                                                                                                             <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                                   <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="GODOWNNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="BATCHNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="DESTINATIONGODOWNNAME" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="INDENTNO"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="ORDERNO"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="TRACKINGNUMBER"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="AMOUNT" type="xs:double"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="ACTUALQTY" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                         <xs:element name="BILLEDQTY" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                                   </xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                             </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                       </xs:element>
                                                                                                                                 </xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                     </xs:element>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="UDF:REFERENCEDATE.LIST">
                                                                                                                           <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                 <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="UDF:REFERENCEDATE" type="xs:int">
                                                                                                                                             <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                                   <xs:attribute name="DESC" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                                                                             </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                       </xs:element>
                                                                                                                                 </xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                 <xs:attribute name="DESC" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                                                                 <xs:attribute name="ISLIST" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                                                                 <xs:attribute name="TYPE" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                     </xs:element>
                                                                                                               </xs:sequence>
                                                                                                               <xs:attribute name="REMOTEID" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                                               <xs:attribute name="VCHTYPE" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                                               <xs:attribute name="ACTION" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                                         </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                   </xs:element>
                                                                                             </xs:sequence>
                                                                                             <xs:attribute name="xmlns:UDF" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                       </xs:complexType>
                                                                                 </xs:element>
                                                                           </xs:sequence>
                                                                     </xs:complexType>
                                                               </xs:element>
                                                         </xs:sequence>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                       </xs:sequence>
                                 </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                     </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
   </xs:schema>
```

Is there anyway to add data to this complex xsd file.

Regards

Comment: Maybe Excel also cannot support the complexibility of this XSD but the main problem is that the XSD is invalid. Element names cannot contain ":" as in <xs:element name="UDF:REFERENCEDATE.LIST"> for example.

Comment: Thank you bringing into notice will update all such errors and give it a try again. :)